# In JavaScript, is there a way to write global functions in a static style? (I'm not sure that I worded that correctly)

Tags: javascript

I know that you can write functions which work if you input different arguments. However, is there a way to add a function which you can write such as
`vector.function(arguments);`.
When I write the functions, I use the vector or object as an argument to get the value back, but is there a way to write it like I have above?

Comment: Please state your question more clearly. It's not obvious what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd like to write a function which can take the vector before the function, such as ```vector.function();``` instead of having to pass in the vector as an argument to return the value.

Comment: You could add your 'function' as a property of the Vector-Prototype. `function Vector() {...} Vector.prototype.yourFunction = function() { /* access vector using "this" */ }`

Comment: If you dont want to pass the argument to the function, you could save it in a variable and can access it from the function implementation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want it an object containing a set of functions inside of it. When functions are defined inside of an objects, these are commonly referred to as "methods". This is a useful way of "namespacing" a set of common methods. You can achieve this in many ways. Here is the most basic way:

```js
const vector = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  getDirection() {
    return Math.atan2(this.y, this.x);
  },
};

console.log(vector.getDirection());
```

This will work fine if you only need one vector. If you want to have many vectors, you can use instantiation to create as many vectors as you need. For example:

```js
// Globally defined function
function getDirection(x, y) {
  return Math.atan2(y, x);
}

function Vector(x = 0, y = 0) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.getDirection = () => {
    // Defer to the globally defined function
    return getDirection(x, y);
  };

  return this;
}

const vectors = [new Vector(10, 15), new Vector(0, 10), new Vector(10, 50)];

vectors.forEach((vector) => {
  console.log(vector.getDirection());
});
```

Comment: Would there be no way to declare a function globally and use it on multiple different vector objects? To put this into context, I have made a separate file which I reference in my HTML file, and written a few functions which I use often to speed up my workflow. I am wondering if I could write a function in there and use it like I've described in my main JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Vector = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
} 

Vector.prototype.yourFunction = function() { 
  /* access vector properties */
  console.log(this.x, this.y);
}

var vector = new Vector(1,2);

vector.yourFunction(); // 1 2
```